# Check if a string containing 2 words is in a dictionary

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have an array of dictionary words and a random string like "twowords"

What is the fastest way to check if the entire string is made up of dictionary words? so "twojwords" would return false and "twowords" returns true

I was using a binary search before but it couldn't handle two word strings

(I'm using objective c)

Comment: For optimization, will the problem always be words of two members, or do you want to extend it to more members, too (like "mytwocents" or "iwanthamburger")?

Comment: more than two members but the string is always 7 letters long, so "ilikeyo" should return true as well

Comment: @GeeGoldz, even if "yo" is not a word?

Comment: @rdineiu it has to be a word, I was just giving that as an example because you is to long

Comment: The 7 letters thing was important input. So the candidate is always 7 letters long and the entries of your dictionary are 1 to 7 letters? Is this urgent, because if not I will implement some ideas I have and do some speed measuring.

Comment: the dictionary is just a dictionary of 200,000 words. Before I was just doing a binary search which works great with one word strings. So the dictionary entries can be 1+ words

Comment: Is this urgent, because if not I will implement some ideas I have and do some speed measuring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a naive approach, but I don't know if there is a faster way.

```
for i1 from 0 to 6 do
  substring1 = string[0..i1];
  if (inDictionary(substring1)) {
    for i2 from i1+1 to 6 do
      substring2 = string[i1+1..i2];
      if (inDictionary(substring2)) {
        for i3 from i2+1 to 6 do 
... (up to i6)
```

For this, you need to be able to form a substring of letters a to b of the string. E.g. if `string = "thisisastring"` then `string[4..7] = "isas"`. You also need a boolean function inDictionary, which should do a binary search for the substring in the dictionary.

This method will work, but depending on the size of the dictionary, may take a bit of time. I believe the English language is currently around 200000 words, in which case any reasonable programming language should have reasonable performance.

Comment: that's a great idea but what does string[0..i1] mean in that language?

Comment: string[a..b] means start at the ath letter and go to the bth letter

Comment: ah, thats pretty obvious, thanks. I'll wait a little longer to choose your answer

Comment: See if you get a more clever approach. I can't see a way to avoid this myself, but I make no false claims of being the smartest person on SO.

Answer (score 4):

One alternative to testing every substring is to build a trie from your dictionary and traverse it, one letter at a time, a la a BFS.  Instead of just keeping track of the current node, we would keep track of the node as well as how many words we had seen. At each node, one would enqueue the next letter if available and also the start node (plus 1 word) if the current node is a terminal node.   If we reach the end of the string and are at the start node with 2 words, then there is a solution.

This neatly generalizes to more than two words.  I'm not sure it is asymptotically faster in the worse case than string spitting, but it will likely be faster because a) there is no word generation b) we know the nth string is in the dictionary before testing the n+1th

Comment: That sounds good but too complicated for me, the substring method is easy

Comment: *shrug* - weren't you complaining that the other solution was too obvious?

Comment: I don't see myself complaining anywhere

Comment: Sorry, guess I misinterpreted one of your comments

Comment: haha it's fine, your answer looks good I just don't want to research BFS, sorry

Comment: I think this is a complicated explanation for a very simple algorithm. Just walk the trie, and whenever you reach a terminal node 1) walk on and 2) restart with the rest of the word. If you ever end up in a terminal node when you reach the end, you know your string is just made up of words. The number of restarts tells you how many words there are in the string.

Comment: You should definitely research BFS (Breadth first search). If you do not know it yet, it is one of the most important algorithms appearing in almost every other problem. Understanding it, will give you a better hang on most other problems.

Answer (score 3):

First, it would be to use some kind of hash table data structure for your dictionary, giving you ~O(1) for a one word lookup. That's a lot better than binary search, especially  when your dictionary is of size 200,000

For two words, split your string into halfs, like t-wowords,tw-owords,two-words,twow-ords etc. and make a lookup for each half.

If you want to allow an arbitrary number of parts, you should try a recursive approach. In pseudocode:

```
bool checkWord(string word)
{
    if(length(word)==1)
        return isWordInDict(word);
    for each pair w1, w2 of word halfs
    {
        if(isWordInDict(w1) && checkWord(w2))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's the best solution is see there.